# Can't read value with elasticsearch-keystore command

Tags: java, elasticsearch, keystore

I have a elasticsearch.keystore file, which is not password-protected. Now I'm trying to read its contents, but [according to this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/elasticsearch-keystore.html) it only support listing the keys:

```
./bin/elasticsearch-keystore list
```

There's no `get` operation for the key printed, what should I do to print the value?

Comment: As far as I know, `Keystore` is read only at startup & the values are cleared from memory after getting processed, except for few values ( Like : Passwords for external services which are retained in memory by the components which leverages them), but the `elasticsearch core` does not retain them at all.

Answer (score 0):

As of https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/76693, which was included in versions 7.16.0 and 8.0.0-beta1, the elasticsearch-keystore CLI now includes the command `show` which displays the value of a single secure setting from the keystore.

Comment: Any option for kibana-keystore? Tried 8.3.0 and still no such command